# "Test Connection" failed from Azure AD for SCIMReferenceCode

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, scim

I am learning SCIM and I wanted to try a few things out locally so I can better understand the concepts. I downloaded the SCIM reference code available here https://github.com/AzureAD/SCIMReferenceCode and I was able to get it running locally and test using the Postman collection found here https://github.com/AzureAD/SCIMReferenceCode/wiki

When I attempt to provision an enterprise application I created in Azure I keep getting failures when I click "Test Connection". The error I am getting is "The Request has attempted to access a forbidden resource. Please ensure that your application is not redirecting requests to a localhost"

For my "Tenant URL" I have it as `https://localhost/5001/scim` and for my "Secret Token", I execute the endpoint `https://localhost/5001/scim/Token` from Postman and then copy/paste the jwt that I got in the response. Could anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you can do it from Azure directly to the localhost. What you can do instead is to try to tunnel traffic from `ngrok` to your local machine.
Here are several steps to follow:

1. Download & install [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/). Make sure to get authtoken.
2. Run your SCIMReferenceCode solution, or any other SCIM service. Check port on which it's running. (let's say it's localhost:51020)
3. Open console and type `ngrok http https://localhost:51020`. Make sure it's running on correct port number. Within the console you should see a table with row `Forwarding`. Open the address you see in the browser (smth like `https://some-random-letters-and-numbers-here.ngrok.io/`
4. Use that url to try to setup provisioning within AzureAD. If you are using `SCIMReferenceCode` sample app you should be able to get secret token from `/scim/token` endpoint.
   [image]

Hope this helps. Now you able to test provisioning from AzureAD to your local machine directly

Answer (score 0):

Dot net core  Web Application will listen to a different port when it runs .

> Microsoft.SCIM.WebHostSample: https://localhost:5001
>
> IIS Express: https://localhost:44359/

**NOTE:**

If project is run locally using IIS Express:

1. Server can be **localhost** ,Por tmust be (**:44359**) (make sure ':' )  ,Api should be **scim**
2. If running locally using Kestrel Port must be “**:5001**” (':' is to be
   noticed)
3. But when hosting the endpoint in Azure please note the **Server must
   be  your SCIM URL**,`Leave the Port blank` and **scim** should holding place    of api.

Please check some of the [known issues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/app-provisioning/application-provisioning-config-problem-scim-compatibility) .

**References:**

1. [use-scim-to-provision | Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/app-provisioning/use-scim-to-provision-users-and-groups#getting-started)
2. [use-scim-to-build-users-and-groups-endpoints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/app-provisioning/use-scim-to-build-users-and-groups-endpoints)